# Windows Workflow Foundation: Error after changing methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, workflow-foundation-4

I'm quite new to Windows Workflow Foundation, but I'm quite enthusiastic about it.
I do have a rather complex WorkFlow implemented that has a couple of input parameters and output parameters, and which executes some methods along the way.

First, I had a Flow decision, which was calling the following method:

```
AdsML.GLNMatching.EmailPresentInDocTrails(platformID, email)
```

This, was executing the following code:

```
public static bool EmailPresentInDocTrails(int _platformId, string email)
{
    var receivingUserGln = BtDbInteract.GetUserByEmail(_platformId, email);
    var returnValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(receivingUserGln);

    return returnValue;
}
```

No real rocket science I guess, now that method has changed to match the following signature:

```
public static bool EmailPresentInDocTrails(int _platformId, string email, string companyId)
```

In my WorkFlow, I've changed the call to the following:

```
AdsML.GLNMatching.EmailPresentInDocTrails(platformID, email, "sdf")
```

According to my knowledge, this is the only thing which I should change.
Now, when I want to compile the project, I receive the following build error:

`No Overload for method 'EmailPresentInDocTrails' takes 2 arguments.`

This doesn't make sense since I've specified 3 parameters. Also, when I view the code (F7) of the the WorkFlow file (XAML), there's only 1 single call to this method being the following:

```
<mca:CSharpValue x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">AdsML.GLNMatching.EmailPresentInDocTrails(platformID, email, "sdf")</mca:CSharpValue>
```

I've tried various things like the following:

- Removing the FlowChart decision and recreate it. - Doesn't work.
- Cleaned the project and build it again. - Doesn't work.
- Restarted Visual Studio  - Doesn't work.

The only solution that I do see here is to remove the WorkFlow and recreate is again from scratch, but this takes time and I don't believe that this is the solution that I should use.

Any help is highly appreciated. 
For your information: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 - Running as Administrator.

Comment: Notice error message, it say 2 arguments, not 3. So your new method is there and working, but somewhere something left what is still calling that old 2 argument version one.

Comment: I've searched the entire Visual Studio solution using the method, but not found anywhere. It seems that Visual Studio is somewhere holding a reference but I don't know where :s

Comment: @Sinatr I've also tried to remove the Obj folder but it doesn't bring a solution.